# With SendGrid API V3, substitutions not working with HTML

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I've got a very simple example that seems like it should work. I'm following their documentation almost exactly.  Here is the simplest code I can think of and it does not substitute the email.

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";

import sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";

(async () => {
  dotenv.config();
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const msg = {
    to: 'test99@gmail.com',
    from: 'sender@example.com',
    subject: 'Welcome to Our Newsletter',
    html: '<html><head></head><body><p>Hello {{name}},</p><p>Thank you for signing up for our newsletter!</p></body></html>',
    substitutions: {
      '{{name}}': 'John Doe' // Replace {{name}} with the recipient's name
    },
  };
  // @ts-ignore
  sgMail.send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Emails sent successfully');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error sending emails:', error);
    });


})();
```

And here is what shows up in my inbox

```
Hello {{name}},

Thank you for signing up for our newsletter!
```

Comment: V3 of the Sendgrid API uses Dynamic Template Data instead of substitutions.

Comment: <https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-templates>

Comment: I’ve concluded that the node library advertised by sendgrid on their primary docs page is just very broken.  sendgrid support says they only support json and that they don’t support any 3rd party libraries.  I’ve switched to JSON and simple POST.  Who in their right mind would use an unsupported library.  Disappointed in Twilio for allowing this.